# Plot histogram bins only if count is above a threshold

Tags: r, histogram

Let's say I have a vector like this:

```
mydata = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

A five-break histogram would look like this:

```
h = hist(mydata, breaks=5)
```

[image]

How can I plot only the bins whose frequency count is above a threshold? In this case, any count greater than 1.

I would like to end up with the following histogram:

[image]

I know I can access the counts and breaks with `h$counts` and `h$breaks` but I cannot think of a simple way to use these to filter out some bins.

Comment: I would caution that this could be a misleading manipulation of data. Is the issue one of multimodality? A similar question might be how to identify optimal bin width so that sparse bins are infrequently populated. Or you might look at varying windows of a density smoother.

Comment: @AdamO, the issue (I don't think) is about multimodality. I have some data with noise (some values being too small) that are still plotted in the histogram (with some bins having a count of 1, compared to other bins that have a count in the order of three or four orders of magnitude.

Comment: Merely adding noise doesn't cause this "issue". It's a known limitation of histograms: if you choose too many bins, there will be intermittent sparse bins. Solution: fewer bins or density smooth. Sparse bins out in the tails should *not* be excluded, they contain key info about the distribution like skewness and range.

Comment: Thank you @AdamO, I had not considered how sparse bins in the tails add information about skewness and range. I will keep them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you can do it like this, but it's not generalizable beyond bins being contiguous and at the left end of the histogram.

```
f <- -which(h$counts < 2)
h[1:4] <- lapply(h[1:4], "[", f)
h
# $breaks
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10
# 
# $counts
# [1] 2 2 2 2
# 
# $density
# [1] 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1111111
# 
# $mids
# [1] 3 5 7 9
# 
# $xname
# [1] "mydata"
# 
# $equidist
# [1] TRUE
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "histogram"
```

If you want to cover cases where the bins are at either ends you'll have to step up a little in code complexity.

```
mydata <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12)
h <- hist(mydata, breaks=6)

f1 <- h$counts < 2
f2 <- rle(f1)
if (length(f2$lengths) == 3) {
    f2$lengths[2] <- f2$lengths[2] + 1
    f2 <- which(inverse.rle(f2))
} else {
    f2 <- which(f1)
}

h[2:4] <- lapply(h[2:4], "[", !f1)
h[[1]] <- h[[1]][-f2]

plot(h)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming if the bucket that's below the threshold is in the middle of the histogram, you just want to drop the bucket.

Given that, it's a matter of adjusting your axis limits to the first and last non-zero buckets.

So far an initial histogram

```
mydata2 <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 10, 12)

h2 <- hist(mydata2, breaks=6)
```

[image: before]

It would be transformed like this

```
h2$counts[ h2$counts < 2] <- 0
xmin <- h2$breaks[min(which(h2$counts != 0))] 
xmax <- h2$breaks[max(which(h2$counts != 0)) + 1] 
plot(h2, xlim = c(xmin, xmax))
```

[image: after]

If you want to merge the middle bucket into other frequencies, then that gets more complicated and depends on what merging rules you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly manipulate the object returned by `hist` and plot it:

```
h$counts[ h$counts < 2 ] <- 0
plot(h)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to remove the bin altogether? As it is right now, the bin would still be there but the bar is removed.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the `hist()` function, since you cannot get a broken up x scale (when one of the bins you wish to remove is between other bins). You would have to plot it yourself, e.g. using `plot` and `rect` or in ggplot2. Take a look at `graphics:::plot.histogram` for inspiration.

Comment: Thank you, I will check them out. But what about when all the discarded bins were at the edges of the x-axis? Then, the x scale would not be broken.